# Showing post data from logged in user only swift/xcode/firebase

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, parent-child

Hey I have been following tutorials online to try and make a social media app and it works fine where all the posts made by users populates in one scene but in another scene I would like for the users who are currently logged in to be able to see their posts only instead of having to find their posts from a bunch of posts made by other users, below are my code samples:

Posts Code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase


class Posts{

var id: String
var author: UserProfile
var text: String
var timestamp:Double
var createdAt:Date


init(id:String, author:UserProfile,text:String,timestamp:Double) {
    self.id = id
    self.author = author
    self.text = text
    self.timestamp = timestamp
    self.createdAt = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp / 1000)
}


static func parse(_ key:String, _ data:[String:Any]) -> Posts? {

    if let author = data["author"] as? [String:Any],
        let uid = author["uid"] as? String,
        let name = author["name"] as? String,
        let photoURL = author["photoURL"] as? String,
        let url = URL(string:photoURL),
        let text = data["text"] as? String,
        let timestamp = data["timestamp"] as? Double {

        let userProfile = UserProfile(uid: uid, name: name, photoURL: url)
        return Posts(id: key, author: userProfile, text: text, timestamp:timestamp)


        func performDeepQuery() {
             guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else { return }
            let uid = user.uid
            let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
            let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "author/uid").queryEqual(toValue: uid)
            query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                let allPosts = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
                for postSnap in allPosts {

                    let text = postSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "text").value as? String ?? "No Text"
                    print(text)
                   //same as above
                }
            })
        }



  }

  return nil }
 }

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
     return 2

 }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     switch section {
            case 0:
                return theposts.count
            case 1:
                return fetchingMore ? 1 : 0
            default:
                return 0
            }    }


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 { let cell = HomeViewControllerScene.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! Posting_TableViewCell
     cell.set(theposts: theposts[indexPath.row])
     return cell}
 else {
         let cell = HomeViewControllerScene.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "loadingCell", for: indexPath) as! LoadingCell
         cell.spinner.startAnimating()
         return cell
     }
 }


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


     cellHeights[indexPath] = cell.frame.size.height
 }


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return cellHeights[indexPath] ?? 72.0
    }
```

Please someone help me out here I have been scratching my head for a while with this!!!

Comment: Without having to parse through that code, are you saying you want to have a view within a scene that only shows posts made by the currently logged in user (e.g. just their own posts)? If so, that would just be a query for posts they made and it's covered in the Firebase getting started guide [Filtering Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data). Is there something more? Also, including a snippet of your Firebase structure can be very helpful. To get your structure, use the console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful and you are correct in presuming that it is just for their own posts but what line of code is required for it as there are a lot of different queries.

Comment: @Jay I think it would be placed in the first code I have on here as I am using the query to order it by timestamp. But anyone logged in can see their posts and posts made by other users but I want to be able to only show the posts of the current user that is logged in.

Comment: @Jay I have edited my question showing the line of code that orders my data currently by timestamp.

Comment: A query ordering by timestamp has nothing to do with a a user seeing their own posts. If there's a 1000 posts ordering it (sorting) will simply sort it. You need to craft a query that only loads posts made by that user. We could help with that but without seeing your structure (as I previosly requested) we won't be able to help. Also, are you displaying the user posts in a separate viewController or are do you want to use the same controller and use some kind of filter - say, the user clicks a button that says 'Show Only My Posts'?

Comment: Understood. You don't need to export JSON or anything like that. All you need to do is when the new viewController opens, run a query on Firestore for the data you want. For example `thisUsersPosts = postsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "uid").queryEqual(toValue: "this users uid")`. I could be more specific if your Firestore structure was included in the question (as I mentioned in my first comment).

Comment: Maybe? I don't know what the keys correspond to. Are they .childByAutoId or user ids? If not, where are the user id's stored? I think we need smaller snippet of your structure and a description of what it is. Oh, it’s a good idea to include code and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure.

Comment: Please see the edited question @Jay

Comment: Withe the current code, the uid var is path reference, not a uid `let uid = Database.database().reference().child("users").child("profile")` which resolves to `your_firebase/users/profile` so then this code `.queryEqual(toValue: uid)` resolves to `.queryEqual(toValue: your_firebase/users/profile)` which is obviously not a uid.

Comment: I deleted a lot of my comments on my answer because they didnt apply after your updates and have updated the answer to demonstrate how to get the current users uid. Give it a try. If it still not working, please clean up your question with well-formatted and current code.

Comment: I just copy and pasted the code from `func performDeepQuery` in your question into a project, added some data to my Firebase and it worked perfectly! Good job. If my answer helped, please be sure to accept it so it can help others.

Comment: Haha it is working but it is on my console but not populating on my screen so I just need to figure out how to do that thanks!

Comment: @Jay How would I move it from console to app?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. The console is output from your app. Are you asking how to display it in a tableView or some other UI element?

Comment: Yeah, I have added the code for my table view in my question because it is not displaying the current users post in the table view, just in the console.

Comment: Well, you're right in that the tableView won't display anything; it's because the dataSource the tableView is using is empty `cell.set(theposts: theposts[indexPath.row])`. You have to populate that array with the data from Firebase. If you are doing that, it's not reflected in the question at all. Since you now know how to read the firebase data, if you need help with tableViews and working with dataSources in general, perhaps a different question related to that specific issue would be in order.

Comment: @Jay I have made a new question https://stackoverflow.com/q/62199497/13619558

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the question is how to get the posts for a certain user. The structure looks good but no need to have a child node 'author' in each post so instead of this:

```
posts
   post_id_0
      author
         author data
      text: "Hello, World"
      uid: "uid_0"
```

do this

```
posts
   post_id_0
      text: "Hello, World"
      uid: "uid_0"
      name: "usmaan"
      photoURL:"https://firebasestorage..."
```

So now just query for this users posts (this is for Firestore, scroll down fo the RTDB solution)...

```
func getThisUsersPosts() {
    let uid = "uid_0" //this users uid
    self.db.collection("posts]").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: uid).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if let err = error {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        if let doc = snapshot?.documents {
            for d in doc {
                let text = d.get("text") as? String ?? "No Post Text"
                print(text)
            }
        } else {
            print("no posts found")
        }
    }
}
```

self.db points to my Firestore.

**EDIT:**

OP is using the Real Time Database so here's the code for that

```
func getThisUsersPosts() {
    let uid = "uid_0"
    let ref = self.ref.child("posts") //self.ref points to MY firebase.
    let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "uid").queryEqual(toValue: uid)
    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let allPosts = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        for postSnap in allPosts {
            let text = postSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "text").value as? String ?? "No Text"
            print(text)
        }
    })
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

OP wants to keep their same structure.

To query for data that's two levels deep we use what's called Deep Query and will look something like this:

```
func performDeepQuery() {
    let uid = "uid_0"
    let ref = self.ref.child("posts")
    let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "author/uid").queryEqual(toValue: uid)
    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let allPosts = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        for postSnap in allPosts {
           //populate your tableView datasource here
           let post = PostClass()
           post.postId = postSnap.key
           post.name = postStap.childSnapshot("name").value as? String ?? "No Post Name"
           post.text = postStap.childSnapshot("text").value as? String ?? "No Post Text"
           self.postArray.append(post)
        }
        self.myTableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

which will perform a deep query on this structure

```
posts
   post_0
      author
         uid: "uid_0"
      name: "post 0 name"
      text: "post 0 text"
```

The PostClass could be this

```
class PostClass {
   var postId = ""
   var name = ""
   var text = ""
}
```

**More Info:**

To get the current users uid (which is covered in the getting started guide as well) and assuming you are authenticated (otherwise it will be nil)

```
guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else { return }
let uid = user.uid
```

Comment: Please see the edited question i changed my code snippet... The way the structure works is that once a user has been created the database stores that information in the users node and then when that person has logged in the program knows who has logged in and then whatever posts are made it will know which user has made the posts.

Comment: @Usmaan Correct. I don't know how you're working with the uid so I made my code match my example data, where it shows *uid_0*. This would typically be how you get it `let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser.uid`

Comment: Ah so replace the "uid_0" with Auth.auth().currentUser.uid ? also it says that db ***Value of type 'HomeViewController' has no member 'db'***

Comment: I understand what you're saying now but is there a way to do it with the current structure that I have?

Comment: thanks for all of this help I am still learning the ropes as you can see but I do appreciate the time and patience you are having here. I keep getting an error *** "You can only pass nil, NSString or NSNumber to queryEqualToValue:" *** when I run my program.