# Populating firebase information into tableView

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, tableview

Hi I am wanting to populate some data from my firebase to my tableView but do not really understand how to go about doing it. Below is a snippet from my code detailing where the data is coming from and the current tableView arrangement I have:

**Edited Attempt**

```
func fetchPosts(completion:@escaping (_ theposts:[Posts])->()){




      oldPostQuery.queryLimited(toLast: 20).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

          var tempPosts = [Posts]()

          let lastPost = self.theposts.last
          for child in snapshot.children {
          if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
              let data = childSnapshot.value as? [String:Any],
              let theposts = Posts.parse(childSnapshot.key, data),
              childSnapshot.key != lastPost?.id {
                  guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else { return }
                         let uid = user.uid
                         let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
                         let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "author/uid").queryEqual(toValue: uid)
                         query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                             let allPosts = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
                             for postSnap in allPosts {

                                 let textUser = postSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "text").value as? String ?? "No Text"
                                 print(textUser)
                                //same as above
                             }
                         })

                      tempPosts.insert(theposts, at: 0)
              }



          }

          return completion(tempPosts)
      } )

  }
```

I am aware that the tableView I am using is empty cell.set(theposts: theposts[indexPath.row]) but I was using this prior as this is the only way I know how to get the data. The information appears in my console but does not populate on the display.

Comment: Could you please format the code.

Comment: Is it not already?

Comment: @Usmaan https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide definitely get into the habit of writing and sharing clean code (it will help you immeasurably)

Comment: @bsod how is that?

Comment: You're not doing anything with the fetched posts so therefore there's nothing to display in the tableView. e.g. `theposts[indexPath.row]` has nothing in it.

Comment: theposts is taking information from my Posts class, what can I do to get that information in that tableView

Comment: No, `theposts` contains nothing as there's no code to populate it. With programming you have to  populate your variables; for example let x = 1 makes the x variable have the value of 1. Within your firebase function, you'll need to create a Post object, `let aPost = Post()` and then populate it's variables with data using your `parse` function and then append that object to `theposts` array `theposts.append(aPost)`. Once it's populated you'll need to the tell the tableView to reload it's data `tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: @Jay I have done that previously as seen in the edited question which allowed me to see the data to begin with where all the users posts were being displayed.

Comment: Let me try this again. The code you're saying works **isn't complete**; it's not populating the array with data, therefore your tableView won't display anything. You need to provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code in your question that duplicates the issue. As is, it doesn't work because you coded it that way! You need to take the code that loads the data correctly (the code I provided you) and modify it to populate the array. **THAT** is the code that should be in the question if it's not working. Make sense?

Comment: @Jay Please see the edited question attempt.

Comment: Again, the code is incomplete and what you're trying to do is unclear. For example; we don't know what this `oldPostQuery` represents or why it's needed. You've got an outer observe function (which as stated, we don't know what that's for) but then an inner observe function (Which is the one I provided) but then all you do in that closure `for postSnap in allPosts {` is to print the text and it does nothing else.  Do you want to do something with that text? That `if let childSnapshot` statement is a mile long and if any one test fails, it all fails silently and you'll never know why.

Comment: You should really go back to my answer to your prior question [Deep Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62046489/showing-post-data-from-logged-in-user-only-swift-xcode-firebase) and look in the **Edit 2** section as that code loads all of the posts, populates a PostClass for each post and then adds that to the tableView dataSource Array.